# Displaying (rendering) HTML from a string in QT

Tags: c++, html, user-interface, qt, qt4

I have html in a QString, what widget can I use to display it?
(QWebView is not necessary as I dont access Internet)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[QWebView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebview.html)s [`setHtml()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebview.html#setHtml):

> The QWebView class provides a widget that is used to view and edit web documents.

In Qt `QWebView` is *the* widget that renders pages for you - if you don't need the networking features it provides, simply don't use them.

Comment: @Regof: No, if you need web content rendering you need to use the QtWebKit module.

Comment: that is not nessecarily true, see my answer below -- you could potentially use a `QTextEdit` depending on what your HTML is.

Comment: @swanson: Ok, i didn't think the OP was ok with displaying subsets of old HTML versions.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on what HTML tags you are using, you might be able to get away with a `QTextEdit`.  It has support for most of HTML, including tables and images.  Take a look at the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#using-qtextedit-as-a-display-widget) and see if it fits your particular needs.

If you need something more advanced, then you will have to use the widgets in `QtWebKit`.